# How to write a select query to get the index value from Json object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have the below JSON object. I need to write a select query to get the index values of `Object` JSON array. Kind of getting the sequence value.

```
{
  "Model": [
    {
      "ModelName": "Test Model",    
      "Object": [
         {
           "ID": 1,
           "Name": "ABC",
         },
         {
           "ID": 11,
           "Name": "ABCD",
         },
          {
           "ID": 15,
           "Name": "ABCDE",
         },
   ]  
}]}
```

Expected Output:

```
Index_Value
  1
  2
  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly and you want to get the index of the items in the `Object` JSON array, you need to use `OPENJSON()` with default schema. The result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and in case of JSON array, the `key` column holds the index of each item in the array (0-based):

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
   "Model":[
      {
         "ModelName":"Test Model",
         "Object":[
            {
               "ID":1,
               "Name":"ABC"
            },
            {
               "ID":11,
               "Name":"ABCD"
            },
            {
               "ID":15,
               "Name":"ABCDE"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, j2.[key]) + 1 AS item_id
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.Model') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value], '$.Object') j2
```

But if you want to get the values of the `ID` keys in the `Object` JSON array, the statement is different:

```
SELECT j2.ID
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.Model') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value], '$.Object') WITH (
   ID int '$.ID'
) j2
```

Note, that you need two `OPENJSON()` calls, because the input JSON has nested array structure. Of course, if `Model` JSON array has always one item, you may simplify the statement using an appropriate `path`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, [key]) + 1 AS item_id
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.Model[0].Object')
```

Finally, to get `index`, `ID` and `Name`, you should use the following statement, which assumes, that `$.Model` JSON array has more than one item and defines `ID` and `Name` columns with the appropraite data types:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(int, j2.[key]) + 1  AS ItemID, 
   j3.ID, j3.Name
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.Model') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value], '$.Object') j2
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j2.[value], '$') WITH (
   ID int '$.ID',
   Name varchar(50) '$.Name'
) j3
```

Comment: The above queries are working but how can I get Index, ID and Name values in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
   "Model":[
      {
         "ModelName":"Test Model",
         "Object":[
            {
               "ID":1,
               "Name":"ABC"
            },
            {
               "ID":11,
               "Name":"ABCD"
            },
            {
               "ID":15,
               "Name":"ABCDE"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}'
declare @i int=0; 
SELECT 
   j2.ID, j2.Name
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.Model') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value],concat('$.Object[',@i,']')) WITH (
   ID i`enter code here`nt '$.ID', Name varchar(100) '$.Name'
) j2
```

Results:-

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | ABCD |

Answer (score 0):

you can select the key columns in select clause no need to mention in with of crossjoin.

```
SELECT 
   distinct t.id,
   JSON_VALUE(AttsData.[value], '$.address') as address,
   JSON_VALUE(AttsData.[value], '$.name') as name,
   JSON_VALUE(AttsData.[value], '$.owner_name') as owner_name,
   JSON_VALUE(AttsData.[value], '$.project') as project
   ,CONVERT(int, AttsData.[key]) index_id
   FROM mytablewithjsonfeild t
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (t."jsonfeild",N'$.parentkey') as   AttsData
```

Above query, from the table  I have cross joined the JSON field. and in select statement i have taken the specific keys.

and `CONVERT(int, AttsData.[key])` to get the index of the elements